# Fixing RuntimeError: Invalid NLS_LANG format: AMERICAN

Tags: ruby, oracle

I'm trying to hit Oracle from Ruby and getting an error on the first line.  (I'm actually doing this in pry, but that probably doesn't matter.)

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'oci8'
RuntimeError: Invalid NLS_LANG format: AMERICAN
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

[Googling the error message](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=%22RuntimeError:+Invalid+NLS_LANG+format:+en_US.UTF-8%22) didn't turn up anything promising. (It ***now*** turns up this question.)  The only other question resembling this one on stackoverflow is dealing with a different problem (the variable not having any value at all even though the user set one) and the answer there did not work for me (the value proposed is also invalid, and `$LANG` is not set in my environment, so setting it to that did not work.)

Comment: whoops... the one in the body is the original, I then tried the other value, and that didn't fix it... I'll update the title to be consistent with the original problem instead of my first attempt at fixing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NLS_LANG` should have the format `<language>_<territory>.<characterset>`

Straight from [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15667/app_gblsupp.htm#sthref1115) there is an example corresponding to your exact use case:

> The NLS_LANG environment variable is set as a local environment variable for the shell on all UNIX-based platforms. For example, **if the operating system locale setting is en_US.UTF-8, then the corresponding NLS_LANG environment variable should be set to AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8**.

Please note the `AL32UTF8` is a superset of `UTF8` (without hyphen) accepting all Unicode characters. `UTF8` only supports Unicode 3.1 and earlier. I would strongly recommend using `AL32UTF8` as your default "UTF-8" character set unless you have very specific needs.

In Oracle 12.1, `AL32UTF8` supports Unicode up to 6.1. One advantage is `AL32UTF8` has support for [supplementary characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm#sthref681) introduced by Unicode 4.0 (code points from U+10000 to U+10FFFF)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the value "AMERICAN" came from, but it turns out a better option, which the ruby-oci8 gem will accept, is [`NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`](https://community.oracle.com/thread/687291?start=0&tstart=0).